# Is there a size limit for the PHP exit()?

Tags: php

I have this issue when using exit($message). Message size is over 50 MB and is only printing ~47 MB. Is there a known limit size the exit construct ?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why not echo your message, then exit right after that?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Is there a size limit for `echo`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273814/are-there-any-length-limits-on-php-echo)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Fair enough :) And yeah, it could be related to that, alex. Cristhian, how are you getting this data?

Comment: wow, I honestly think that probably noone ever has ever tried to print the entire unabridged works of shakespear as an exit message which should be just straight to the point like "failed to connect to database" or such..

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu expect the unexpected :)

Comment: @ChrisForrence  This is just some bug ina  legacy spaghetti code. They get a value from blob field in table and uses exit() to download it as file later  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯